# How can I prove this statement by mathematical induction?

Tags: induction

I'm having trouble proving that
$$n! \leqslant n^n \, \, \, \,\forall \,n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$$
by mathematical induction.
I checked if it worked for $n = 1$ and then supposed that it worked for $n$, to then prove if it worked for $n+1$.

In this last step I tried writing $(n+1)!$ like $n!(n+1)$ but I don't know how to continue. Thank you so much.

Comment: You're on the right track:  
$n!(n+1) \leqslant n^n(n+1) \leqslant(n+1)^n(n+1)=(n+1)^{n+1}$

Comment: A [simple search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24n!%20%5Cleqslant%20n%5En%20%24%2C%20induction&p=1) can get you many relevant answers for common questions.

Comment: Here is a video explaining: https://youtu.be/NsO6nh42oPo

Comment: Another approach: Note that $\frac{n!}{n^n} = \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n}$. Then, use induction to prove that the product of $n$ numbers less than $1$ is also less than $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n! \le n^n$.

Since $n^n \le (n+1)^n$ we get

$$(n+1)!=n!(n+1) \le n^n(n+1) \le (n+1)^n(n+1) = (n+1)^{n+1}.$$

Comment: Thank you so much! You solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

$n! (n+1) \le n^n(n+1)$ by induction assumption, and $n^n(n+1) < (n+1)^n(n+1)$ because $n<n+1$.

Answer (score 1):

$n^{n}<(n+1)^{n}$ So $(n+1)(n^{n})<(n+1)^{n+1}$. Hence, if we assume that $n! <n^{n}$ we get $(n+1)!=(n+1) n! <(n+1) n^{n}<(n+1)^{n+1}$